# How can I move this JS code outside of the HTML script tag in a real application (CakePHP)?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, highcharts, export

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap

I have been just embedding the JS in an HTML script tag, but that is probably not ideal.
I tried moving the JS to an external customfilename.js file under webroot/js/CustomFileDirectory, and then adding this to the .ctp (CakePHP template) file:

```
<?= $this->Html->script('CustomFileDirectory/customfilename.js', array('block' => 'scriptBottom')); ?>
```

However, it doesn't really work, because the "Highcharts" variable is undefined. I think I can only use ES5 (rather than ES6). I think Highcharts is most likely referencing the highcharts.js file being references in one of the other html script tags. How can I make this work?

Comment: Have you considered installing the Highcharts page through the npm? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm

Comment: Interesting, I did not know you could. I think I ran into some errors when running it though and just continued with the script tags.